# How to handle a second onClick to initiate an API request using reactJS and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am new to redux, and I am creating a small app to render an API onClick. I call the action creator inside the componentDidMount which is able to generate the desired outcome the first click. However, because componentDidMount only renders once, nothing happens upon the second "click".

The following code is the component containing the onClick called "handleFavClick" inside this function two action creators are triggered one to identify the button that was clicked and add it to the state for use in the second action creator, which gets the API.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../stylesheet/FavoriteList.css';
import { uploadGif } from '../actions';

import Display from './Display';




class FavoriteList extends React.Component {


handleFavClick = (id) => {
    this.props.uploadGif(id);
    this.displayGif();
}

displayGif = () => {
    this.setState({display: true});
};


renderList = (callback) => {
    let fullList = this.props.favsList.map(function(cur, index) {
        return (
        <button onClick={function() {
            callback(index);
        }} className="list-item" key={index}>{cur}</button>
        )
    });
    return fullList;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="favs">
                <h2>Favorite List</h2>
                <ul className="unordered-list">
                    {this.renderList(this.handleFavClick)}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {this.state.display && <Display />}
        </div>

    )
}
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
uploadGif,

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
favsList: state.myFirstReduxKey,

}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FavoriteList);
```

Display Component (after onClick is triggered, this component is rendered and the display is updated with the data received from the API request)

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getGif } from '../actions';

class Display extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const list = this.props.gifList;
        const item = this.props.chosenGif;
        this.props.getGif(list[item]);
   }

.
.
.
.

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
    gifList: state.myFirstReduxKey,
    chosenGif: state.uploadGif,
    gifs: state.getGif
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGif })(Display);
```

Called Action Creator

```
export const getGif = (action) => async dispatch => {
    const key = 'GRghbyFwY5CEhc1h7ngS9KBEK9s2W3zBa'
    const response = await gifApi.get(`search?q=${action}&api_key=${key}`)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data.data
    });


    dispatch({ type: GET_GIF, payload: response})
};
```

At the end of the day, I would like to know how redux programmers handle a client clicking one button, which renders something, then a client clicks a new button which removes the prior click's rendering and renders the new information.

Comment: where is your component which has the "onclick" property that should call the action ? post complete code please

Comment: Sorry, Tarreq. I just saw this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but there is one thing you need to change to make this work has expected, like how you said since your code is in `componentDidMount`, this is gonna work only in the **Creational life cycle** of the component, 
now there are two things you can do.

**1.**Move your `this.props.getGif(list[item])` into **render()** (**Recomended**):

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';    
 import { getGif } from '../actions';

    class Display extends React.Component {
       render(){
            const list = this.props.gifList; //this code gets executed every time
            const item = this.props.chosenGif;
            this.props.getGif(list[item]);
       }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
       return {
        gifList: state.myFirstReduxKey,
        chosenGif: state.uploadGif,
        gifs: state.getGif
      }
    }


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGif })(Display);
```

**2.Have a separate handler and have both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` call it:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getGif } from '../actions';

class Display extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
        this.loadGifHandler();
   }

   componentDidUpdate() {
        this.loadGifHandler();
   }


   loadGifHandler = () => {
        const list = this.props.gifList;
        const item = this.props.chosenGif;
        this.props.getGif(list[item]);
   }

.
.
.
.

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
    gifList: state.myFirstReduxKey,
    chosenGif: state.uploadGif,
    gifs: state.getGif
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGif })(Display);
```

Comment: I am trying to work with this solution. The issue is that getGif() is an action-creator and after running, it re-renders the component causing a loop.

Comment: Is getGif() a asynchronous action creator ?

Comment: Yes. It uses axios to return the JSON object from an API.

Comment: I found an answer. I forgo creating a separate component for the results of the API request and just initiated and displayed the API request inside the onClick function inside the search bar component. Everything is happening in the same component, but it works.  Thanks for trying Praveen, and I will remember your answer for future use!

Comment: happy to help :)